# Install Dagster on M1 MacBook

Tags: mac, command-line, apple-silicon, software

I am trying to install Dagster on my M1 MacBook Pro with pip. But keep getting these error messages.

`ImportError: dlopen(/Users/test/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-pRGt4I8q/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/test/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-pRGt4I8q/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)`

Comment: It would seem from this error that the files at `/Users/test/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-pRGt4I8q/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so` are not compatible with the `arm64e` architecture.   These files are for Intel based Mac only `x86_64`.  You will need to talk to whomever maintains the code to see what the plans for Apple Silicon are.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - it worked on my M1 Max MacBook Pro:

- `python3 -m venv dagster`
- `source dagster/bin/activate`
- `pip3 install dagster dagit`

```
(dagster) (base) Charlie:test sfederman$ dagster
Usage: dagster [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  CLI tools for working with Dagster.

Options:
  -v, --version  Show the version and exit.
  -h, --help     Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  asset        Commands for working with Dagster assets.
  debug        Commands for debugging Dagster pipeline/job runs.
  instance     Commands for working with the current Dagster instance.
  job          Commands for working with Dagster jobs.
  new-project  Create a new Dagster repository and generate boilerplate code.
  pipeline     Commands for working with Dagster pipelines/jobs.
  run          Commands for working with Dagster pipeline/job runs.
  schedule     Commands for working with Dagster schedules.
  sensor       Commands for working with Dagster sensors.
```

If this doesn't work for you, something may be awry with your python3 installation.